# Migrating Javascript from the database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, database, architecture

I am working on an old enterprise solution with these properties:

- The solution has a MVC web application
- The solution has a WCF service layer
- The solution has javascript in the database, in the form of functions in a database column
- The web application retrieves said javascript through the service layer and plugs it into certain pages
- My team cannot modify the web application, nor the service layer
- My team must write javascript by inserting functions into said database columns

This architecture leads to:

- A very inefficient development loop
- Very poor source control

I'd like to propose a solution for them, how to upgrade this, but here's where I fall a bit short on experience. My suggestion would be:

1. Migrate the javascript from the database to javascript files
2. Make some sort of hook in the web application for other teams' javascript files

My questions are:

- Has anyone had this kind of problem and how did they solve it?
- Is there an effective way to do this kind of javascript migration into files? My idea would be to write a small console program to do the migration
- How would they make a hook to import our javascript files? My idea is to make a script bundle with some naming convention, so we can add scripts without them needing to change their code. Are there problems with this approach?

Any kind of input would be invaluable.

Edit:

Additional explanation:

- The mechanism maps the javascript function names to a certain DOM elements' event attributes and inlines the code right after the element
- The functions are standalone functions, depending only on libraries already in the web application
- The functions are grouped by a common form

So I suppose it would be better to group them into files bearing the form names.

Comment: How does the web application know which javascript to plugin to which page? This could be a critical piece of information in constructing an answer. Is it a simple map one-to-one with the same page, or is it dynamic based on user interaction? Things could get weird... haha

Comment: I've added an explanation of the mapping mechanism. You were right to assume that these are indeed standalone functions. And they do group by form, but they are not functionally grouped.

Answer (score 1):

If these are just simple, static function definitions being inlined into the web page, then I suppose it might be possible to serialize/aggregate them all into a giant file and run something like [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) on it to make it readable.

That wouldn't be ideal to gain traction in your proposed migration, though. If the code has any volume to it at all, it would be nice to give some structure and order to maintain it.

It's already kind of a huge assumption that this javascript is just pure functions without any complex dependencies on each other, but it's possible that these pieces of Javascript work in isolation already if they are being pulled out of a database. It's hard to know without knowing more context. It seems unlikely that your life will be that easy.

If you managed to extract this monolithic Javascript file, the easiest thing to do would be include it in a script tag for the entire site and be done with it. This could be a bad idea if the file is getting to the ~MB size and slows your initial page load time.

Then again, the point at which you have a bunch of functions in one file, you could probably do a lot there to optimize and reduce duplication of code.

This is still all conjecture because I don't know the mechanism by which your web application imports the javascript once it retrieves it from the database.